# JPA 2.1 / Hibernate 5.0 Generating schema ignores foreignKey name in inverseJoinColumn

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ddl

I tried generatind a DDL with JPA 2.1 and Hibernate 5.0 but somehow I do something wrong and it ignores the name of the foreignkey in the `inverseJoinColumn` definition.

These are my entities:

Parent:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT", indexes = { @Index(columnList = "NAME", name = "IDX_NAME") }, uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "NAME", name = "UK_NAME") })
@SequenceGenerator(allocationSize = 1, name = "PARENT_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "PARENT_ID_SEQ")
public class Parent {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "PARENT_ID_GENERATOR", strategy = SEQUENCE)
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "NAME")
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(name = "PARENT_CHILD", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID"), foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name ="FK_PARENT_CHILD_PARENT"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CHILD_ID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name ="FK_ABC")), uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "CHILD_ID", name = "UK_CHILD_ID") })
  private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Child:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHILD", indexes = { @Index(columnList = "NAME", name = "IDX_NAME") }, uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "NAME", name = "UK_NAME") })
@SequenceGenerator(allocationSize = 1, name = "CHILD_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "CHILD_ID_SEQ")
public class Child {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "CHILD_ID_GENERATOR", strategy = SEQUENCE)
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "NAME")
  private String name;
}
```

I wrote the following small main class to generate the ddl

SchemaCreator:

```
public class SchemaCreator {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        execute("default", "./target/create.sql");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void execute(String persistenceUnitName, String destination) {
        System.out.println("Generating DDL create script to : " + destination);

        final Properties persistenceProperties = new Properties();

        persistenceProperties.setProperty(org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "");
        persistenceProperties.setProperty(AvailableSettings.SCHEMA_GEN_DATABASE_ACTION, "none");

        persistenceProperties.setProperty(AvailableSettings.SCHEMA_GEN_SCRIPTS_ACTION, "create");
        persistenceProperties.setProperty(AvailableSettings.SCHEMA_GEN_CREATE_SOURCE, "metadata");
        persistenceProperties.setProperty(AvailableSettings.SCHEMA_GEN_SCRIPTS_CREATE_TARGET, destination);
        persistenceProperties.setProperty(AvailableSettings.JDBC_DRIVER,"org.h2.Driver");
        persistenceProperties.setProperty(AvailableSettings.JDBC_URL,"jdbc:h2:mem:jpaschema");
        Persistence.generateSchema(persistenceUnitName, persistenceProperties);
    }

}
```

My persistence.xml looks like this

persist

```
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.1"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
                            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="default">

    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

    <class>nl.generate.ddl.example.Child</class>
    <class>nl.generate.ddl.example.Parent</class>
</persistence-unit>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?
I included the above code in a sample project on github https://github.com/vdmc/generate-ddl-example.git

Comment: The JPA schema annotations all look fine to me, with the only exception that some datastores would object to the multiple indexes of name "IDX_NAME" (one in Parent and one in Child) since the namespace for them is global. If your JPA provider doesn't pick up the FK name then raise a bug on it.

Comment: Thanx for your reply. I changed the index names in the example project. I know there were bugs conceirning this in Hibernate 4 but I also read they closed those tickets and marked them as solved in Hibernate 5.

Comment: Cool thanx. I will take that to Hibernate as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually one thing that is incorrect in your metadata is that on `@JoinTable` there is *"inverseForeignKey"*. Specify your FK info there rather than under *"inverseJoinColumns"*.

```
@JoinTable(name = "PARENT_CHILD", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID"), 
    foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name ="FK_PARENT_CHILD_PARENT"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CHILD_ID"), 
    inverseForeignKey = @ForeignKey(name ="FK_ABC"), 
    uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "CHILD_ID", name = "UK_CHILD_ID") })
```